# How do I store factors of polynomials in a list in sympy?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Suppose I have x^6-1 that I would like to factor, using .factor I get my irreducible factors, but I want those factors in a list. I tried using .factor_list() But it doesn't give me my desired result instead stores them in a tuple and there is always a 1 beside the factors. I want each factored polynomial in a list on its own, how can I do that if possible?

Like for example,

```
from sympy import Symbol, factor, Poly

x = Symbol('x')
p = x**6 - 1
factors = factor(p)
factors
```

that gives me these factors 4 irreducible factors, how do I store them in a list not as a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break a product into a list of factors by forcing the factored result to be treated like a product (whether it is or not); this will give you a tuple of factors. You can use `list` to change this to a list if needed:

```py
>>> from sympy import Mul
>>> list(Mul.make_args(factor(x**6-1)))
[x + 1, x - 1, x**2 + x + 1, x**2 - x + 1]
```

You said "I want each factored polynomial in a list on its own, how can I do that if possible"; is this what you mean:

```py
>>> [[i] for i in Mul.make_args(factor(x**6-1))]
[[x + 1], [x - 1], [x**2 + x + 1], [x**2 - x + 1]]
```

What do you want to do with arguments that are repeated?

```py
>>> [b for b,e in factor_list((x+1)*(x**6-1))[1] for i in range(e)]
[x - 1, x + 1, x + 1, x**2 - x + 1, x**2 + x + 1]
>>> [b for b,e in factor_list((x+1)*(x**6-1))[1]]
[x - 1, x + 1, x + 1, x**2 - x + 1, x**2 + x + 1]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [b**(e*c) for (b,e),c in Counter(factor_list((x+1)*(x**6-1))[1]).items()]
[x - 1, (x + 1)**2, x**2 - x + 1, x**2 + x + 1]
```

I don't think that last step should be necessary to combine like factors. I will report that as a bug since the docstring shows another example in which a factor with multiplicity of 2 appears once in a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one last thing, how can I take each polynomial and look at the degree of each term?

Comment: `degree(1+x**2) -> 2`

Comment: Hi, sorry I want to for example take the degree of each term, like 1 has degree of 0 because no x term with it and x^2 is degree 2. in 1+x^2, in the polynomial itself.

Comment: `[degree(a,x) for a in Add.make_args(term)]`

Answer (score 2):

The output of `factor_list` is the leading coefficient and then a list of tuples of monic irreducible factors along with their multiplicity:

```
In [13]: factor_list(x**6 - 1)
Out[13]: 
⎛   ⎡                        ⎛ 2           ⎞  ⎛ 2           ⎞⎤⎞
⎝1, ⎣(x - 1, 1), (x + 1, 1), ⎝x  - x + 1, 1⎠, ⎝x  + x + 1, 1⎠⎦⎠
```

You can just extract the part of the return value that you want from the `factor_list` output:

```
In [12]: [f for f, m in factor_list(x**6 - 1)[1]]
Out[12]: 
⎡               2           2        ⎤
⎣x - 1, x + 1, x  - x + 1, x  + x + 1⎦
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use `as_terms()` method

```py
factors.as_terms()[1]
```

This would produce the following list:

```
[x - 1, x + 1, x**2 - x + 1, x**2 + x + 1]
```